# Improving efficiency of a time consuming program using grid computing

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I have a Java program which takes few hours to complete! Now we have to rewrite it using latest in open source which can reducing the time.

I can think of achieving it by using multiple computers and further multiple threads (All configurable). Can you suggest some open source projects to match this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Go for  [Java Parallel Processing Framework **JPPF**](http://www.jppf.org/)  .

I have personally used it in one of my project ,

If I have understood your requirement than this is the perfect solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out Apache's [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/).  Specifically their MapReduce implementation.  You'll have to compare and see what fits your needs best.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Jini](http://www.jini.org/wiki/Main_Page) and [Javaspaces](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/tools/JavaSpaces/) (an implementation of a [Tuple Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple_space)) ?

Javaspaces make it very easy to implement a scatter/gather grid. You simply push your work units out as serialisable objects into a Javaspace, and run up 'N' consumers to transactionally take those work units, process them, and put them back.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Grid Gain](http://www.gridgain.com/) easy to use. You could also try using [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) to distribute compute and a cache to distribute data. There are many options to distribute data and compute for Java. I agree with @bemace, you should compare the various options against your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com). There is a comparison of several grid computing frameworks:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/comparison-gridcloud-computing-0